# Floating point problems in C and Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision, mex

Hey there,
I have floating point problems in my matlab-mex file where I get values at the magnitude 10^(-12) to 10^(-13)... Is there an 'dirty' way to solve them to at least set those values to zero after the computation if they are so small?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an array, you could do something like:

```
small_inds = find(abs(array) < 10^-12);
array(small_inds) = zeros(length(small_inds),1);
```

(edited to add `abs()` for clarity—thanks nimrodm)

Comment: Would probably be better to use abs(array).
Also - You might want to keep relative accuracy rather than absolute error so use something like max(array(:))*10^-12.

Comment: Yeah thanks, and is this a rather 'dirty' method or is this really 'okay' in computation to set values to zero which are sooo small like 10^-12 or 10^-13!?

Comment: I would say it depends on the application. If you have a long ARMA filter, those coefficients could be really important.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for (I guess the question is do you want this to be done in the mex file, or not), but my trick is to run a logic operations. Say the loaded mex matrix is X

```
Xm = abs(X) > max_error;
X = Xm .* X;
```